# using target=_blank in a gridview row javascript event

Tags: javascript, .net, gridview, onclick

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", location='" + e.Row.Cells[5].Text + "'");
```

works fine but I want the new page to open in a new window.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "target=_blank location='" + e.Row.Cells[5].Text + "'");
```

nothing happens.  The source code inside the tablerow is:

```
onclick="target=_blank location=&#39;http://www.something.com&#39;"
```

Do I need to do a window.open to accomplish this?  If so, can someone provide syntax as my efforts to that effect have not been successful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onclick is looking for javascript... target, used in this fashion, is an attribute for an anchor tag...

(IMO) window.open is your best/easiest option.

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.something.com', 'mywindow')"
```

unless you turn that row item into an anchor:

```
<a href="http://www.something.com" target=_blank>Click Me</a>
```

you can do this by creating a template column and building the link based on the data returned and the template it needs to fit into.

```
open (URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])
```

**Changing the features of the Popup**
You can control the features of the popup using the last argument to the window.open method. The following code opens a window with a status bar and no extra features.

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow","status=1");
```

The code below opens a window with toolbar and status bar.

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com", "mywindow","status=1,toolbar=1");
```

The table shows the features and the string tokens you can use:

**status** The status bar at the bottom of the window.

**toolbar** The standard browser toolbar, with buttons such as Back and Forward.

**location** The Location entry field where you enter the URL.

**menubar** The menu bar of the window

**directories** The standard browser directory buttons, such as What’s New and What’s Cool

**resizable**  Allow/Disallow the user to resize the window.

**scrollbars** Enable the scrollbars if the document is bigger than the window

**height** Specifies the height of the window in pixels. (example: height=’350′)

**width** Specifies the width of the window in pixels.

Information obtained at: [Using the Window Open Method.](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: what is the 'mywindow' argument?  Is that literal or does it represent something else?  And where would the target=_blank argument go in that window.open function?

Comment: its whatever you want to name your window... ill update my response with the window.open syntax in a sec.

Comment: Answered my first question about 'mywindow'.  I see it's the window name.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks Patrick.  Don't even need the target parameter.  window.open defaults to a new window apparently.